# Exception when attempting to subscribe a Google My Business account to receive notifications

Tags: php, review, google-my-business-api

I am trying to subscribe a Google My Business account to receive notifications every time a new review is posted or updated . I am following  Google documents here https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts/updateNotifications and using Google php wrapper MyBusiness.php from github.

I created topic gmn-notification and a subscription  via Goggle Cloud console. I also assigned  Pub/Sub Publisher Role  in this topic  to mybusiness-api-pubsub@system.gserviceaccount.com as Goggle documentation suggested.

Here is relevant excerpt from my code

```
$client = new Google_Client();
...
...
$mybusinessService = new Google_Service_Mybusiness($client);
$accounts = $mybusinessService->accounts;
$accountsList = $accounts->listAccounts()->getAccounts();
foreach ($accountsList as $accKey => $account) {
try
{
    $n=new Google_Service_MyBusiness_Notifications();
    $n->setNotificationTypes(['NEW_REVIEW', 'UPDATED_REVIEW']);
    $n->setTopicName("gmn-notification");
    $nam=$account->name."/notifications";
    $n->setName($nam);
    $notivication=$accounts->updateNotifications($nam,$n);
    error_log("notification=".print_r($notification,1));
} catch(Exception $e)
{
    error_log(print_r($e->getMessage(),1));
}
```

I see that, internally, Google sends the following PUT request which looks good

```
method=PUT
target=/v4/accounts/112497043970166515141/notifications
uri=https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/112497043970166515141/notifications
body={"name":"accounts\/112497043970166515141\/notifications","notificationTypes":["NEW_REVIEW","UPDATED_REVIEW"],"topicName":"gmn-notification"}
```

I am getting the following exception

```
{
 "error": {
   "code": 400,
   "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
   "errors": [
     {
       "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
       "domain": "global",
       "reason": "badRequest"
     }
   ],
   "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
}
```

I am wondering whether anyone can  help.

Comment: have you found solution for this?

Comment: If yes then plz share code excerpt

Comment: I think the problem is your `TopicName` which might be wrong. Usually, it has this structure `projects/{project-name-here}/topics/{topic-name-here}`.